# covering map of complex plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the map $p:\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, $p(z)=z^4$. This is a covering map, which I have shown. 

 If I consider the same map, but defined on the whole plane $p:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, why is this not a covering map?

Comment: Who said it is not?

Comment: The origin has no neighbourhood on which $p$ is injective. Since covering maps are local homeomorphisms, it follows that the extension of $p$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is not a covering map. Unless you do complex analysis and consider branched coverings. Then it's a branched covering of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For covering maps the cardinality of the fiber is constant on path-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the map $p: z \mapsto z^4$ to be a covering map for $\mathbb{C}$, there should be an open neightbourhood $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ containing $0$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of open subsets each of which is homeomorphic to $U$. Moreover this homeomorphism should be given by $p$, however in this case $p$ will not be a bijection.